# Can all files associated with previous Linux be deleted?

Tags: kernel

I am currently using 2.6.32-37 with 2.6.32-36 as a backup. I have various files & dirs (`/boot` `/lib/firmware` `/lib/modules` `/usr/share/doc` `/usr/src` `/var/lib/dpkg/info` `/var/lib/initramfs-tools`) that contain remnants of 2.6.32-24 thru 2.6.32-35.

Can these old files & dirs be removed from my system?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Synaptic installed you can search for "linux-image" and remove the unwanted kernel versions that way.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is removing previous versions of kernels and headers you may want to use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/). Try installing it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Or from your Ubuntu Software Center. You can also clean your packages, cache, config and PPAs with this tool.

Here's a screenshot to whet your appetite:

[image]

Comment: I am using Lynx. I will install when I go to 12.04.